# Why is the derivative not $\lim x\to x_0$ instead of $\lim h\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

As you see in the following image

[image]

you can get a tangent when you are moving towards $x_0$ and not $0$.

But if $\lim \to 0$ then you miss $x_0$ because then you are moving at things from $0$ and then you arent working with $x_0$ anymore.

I understood the proof of "derivative as a limit" up until this. I thought that the limit worked on a specific place so in this place it should had been at x0 because that's where you want the tangent to be. And not 0 because the tangent is not there.

I know I am wrong but I dont know why (i know from textbook and from the khanacadamy video) . Could someone explain why you put $\lim x\to 0$ and not $\lim x\to x_0$?

I think I misunderstood limits :(

Thanks beforehand :)

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That's because of the substitution $x=x_0+h$, so $\;x \to x_0\iff h=x-x_0\to 0$.

Comment: I've revised the editing of your OP. Let try to improve further by yourself, it is quite unclear and confused. Note also that the highlighted part in teh image is $\lim h\to 0$ and not $\lim x\to 0$.

Comment: @Hamzalihi Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 6):

By definition the derivative of $f(x)$ at a point $x=x_0$ is given by (when the limit exists)

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

now if we define $x-x_0=h\to 0$ the limit becomes

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

the two definitions are completely equivalent.

Comment: I might sound stupid but why do you define it? Why would you? I dont understand how you get from you third line to the fourth.

Comment: @Hamzalihi Don't worry any doubts and question is welcome to me! It is only a matter of convention and preference. From the definition for $x\to x_0$ we indicate the difference $h:=x-x_0$ in order to use $h$ for the limit. Then we set $x\to x_0 \iff h\to 0$ and $f(x-x_0)=f(h)$ but nite that the two expression are completely equivalent. It is only a different name for the quantities involved.

Comment: I didnt understand that. First of all at your main comment you have written f(x) instead of f(x-h). why? The video is diferent so what did you do different?

Why would the limit for h go to zero? Why? What do you mean of  "we indicate the difference" ? How do you go from x→x0 to h→0  

Could you explain what happens when you have reached this(https://i.imgur.com/VuuTnXS.png) stage of the proof? 

I cant wrap my head around what you are writing :(

Comment: @Hamzalihi One question at time. In the first line I've indicate what we are calculating, that is the derivative of $f(x)$ at the point $x=x_0$. Why you are thinking to $f(x-h)$?

Comment: @Hamzalihi Note that $x$ tends to $x_0$ and while $x$ becomes closer and closer to $x_0$ the quantity $h=x-x_0$ tends to $0$. It is simply a different way to say the same thing. Anyway, before to go on the lines $3$ and $4$ you need to have really clear the line $2$. Take also a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative